Boot fails after upgrade - "you need to load the kernel first"
After upgrading from Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10, my system does not boot anymore with the error message you need to load the kernel first. When I go into grub-rescue and manually set Linux with root=/dev/nvme0n1p3 (as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first), the system boots. I tried Boot-Repair which runs successfully (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bRzrkjPgQT/), but the system still does not boot.
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p3,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.10 entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.11.0-9-generic
The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p3,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
rm /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi.grb
/dev/nvme0n1p3/boot/efi not empty

=================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/nvme0n1p3 ===================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-5ubuntu5
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.11.0-9-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,001C,0000,001D,001E,001F,0020,0021,0022,0023
Boot0000* Recovery  HD(2,GPT,99c1d0bf-a399-475e-bfd3-fd3d740c9e4a,0x12c800,0xb99998)/File(EFIbootshimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9f5c7faa-0dc3-4343-aab6-2733fc0164ef,0x800,0x12c000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Asset Information FvFile(da465b87-a26f-4c12-b78a-0361428fa026)
Boot0015  Regulatory Information    FvFile(478c92a0-2622-42b7-a65d-5894169e4d24)
Boot0016  ThinkShield secure wipe   FvFile(3593a0d5-bd52-43a0-808e-cbff5ece2477)
Boot0017  ThinkShield Passwordless Power-On Device Manager  FvFile(08448b41-7f83-49be-82a7-0e84790ab133)
Boot0018  Wi-Fi Configuration   FvFile(d3aaff0f-cb22-4792-896c-802c2e9383ba)2d004100700070000000
Boot0019  Reinstall Windows from Cloud  FvFile(3edbaac4-5017-4870-8cc4-721f9ef1974f)2d004100700070000000
Boot001A  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot001B  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot001C* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot001D* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001E* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001F* NVMe1 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a401)
Boot0020* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0021* PXE BOOT  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0022* LENOVO CLOUD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri(https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/cdeploy/efi/boot.efi)
Boot0023* ON-PREMISE    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri()
Boot0024* Boot Next Boot Option VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)

uname -r
6.11.0-9-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p2
touch /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.grb
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,001C,0000,001D,001E,001F,0020,0021,0022,0023
Boot0000* Recovery  HD(2,GPT,99c1d0bf-a399-475e-bfd3-fd3d740c9e4a,0x12c800,0xb99998)/File(EFIbootshimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9f5c7faa-0dc3-4343-aab6-2733fc0164ef,0x800,0x12c000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Asset Information FvFile(da465b87-a26f-4c12-b78a-0361428fa026)
Boot0015  Regulatory Information    FvFile(478c92a0-2622-42b7-a65d-5894169e4d24)
Boot0016  ThinkShield secure wipe   FvFile(3593a0d5-bd52-43a0-808e-cbff5ece2477)
Boot0017  ThinkShield Passwordless Power-On Device Manager  FvFile(08448b41-7f83-49be-82a7-0e84790ab133)
Boot0018  Wi-Fi Configuration   FvFile(d3aaff0f-cb22-4792-896c-802c2e9383ba)2d004100700070000000
Boot0019  Reinstall Windows from Cloud  FvFile(3edbaac4-5017-4870-8cc4-721f9ef1974f)2d004100700070000000
Boot001A  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot001B  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot001C* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot001D* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001E* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001F* NVMe1 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a401)
Boot0020* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0021* PXE BOOT  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0022* LENOVO CLOUD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri(https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/cdeploy/efi/boot.efi)
Boot0023* ON-PREMISE    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri()
Boot0024* Boot Next Boot Option VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/oem-flavour.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1020-oem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-1020-oem
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.11.0-9-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.11.0-9-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Generating 'Restore Ubuntu 22.04 to factory state' entry ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.10 entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/grub.cfg /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.10 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA107GLM [RTX A1000 6GB Laptop GPU] Phoenix1 from NVIDIA Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/nvme0n1p3
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p3 ext4  932G  302G  583G  35% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: N3VET55W (1.55 )(1.55) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,001C,0000,001D,001E,001F,0020,0021,0022,0023
Boot0000* Recovery  HD(2,GPT,99c1d0bf-a399-475e-bfd3-fd3d740c9e4a,0x12c800,0xb99998)/File(\EFI\boot\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9f5c7faa-0dc3-4343-aab6-2733fc0164ef,0x800,0x12c000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Asset Information FvFile(da465b87-a26f-4c12-b78a-0361428fa026)
Boot0015  Regulatory Information    FvFile(478c92a0-2622-42b7-a65d-5894169e4d24)
Boot0016  ThinkShield secure wipe   FvFile(3593a0d5-bd52-43a0-808e-cbff5ece2477)
Boot0017  ThinkShield Passwordless Power-On Device Manager  FvFile(08448b41-7f83-49be-82a7-0e84790ab133)
Boot0018  Wi-Fi Configuration   FvFile(d3aaff0f-cb22-4792-896c-802c2e9383ba)2d004100700070000000
Boot0019  Reinstall Windows from Cloud  FvFile(3edbaac4-5017-4870-8cc4-721f9ef1974f)2d004100700070000000
Boot001A  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot001B  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot001C* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot001D* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot001E* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001F* NVMe1 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a401)
Boot0020* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot0021* PXE BOOT  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0022* LENOVO CLOUD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri(https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/cdeploy/efi/boot.efi)
Boot0023* ON-PREMISE    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,ad38ccbbf7edf04d959cf42aa74d3650)/Uri()
Boot0024* Boot Next Boot Option VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)

ec39b353668287f382b4982241c3aa3a   nvme0n1p2/boot/bootx64.efi (is grub)
dbb73486aa1fffa648f99f31f209f545   nvme0n1p2/boot/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p2/boot/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p2/boot/shimx64.efi
ec39b353668287f382b4982241c3aa3a   nvme0n1p2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p2   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 7EC90D9A-EB5C-4A77-A41D-4C984A5D1AD0
            Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1     2048    1230847    1228800   600M EFI System
nvme0n1p2  1230848   13394327   12163480   5.8G EFI System
nvme0n1p3 13395968 2000409230 1987013263 947.5G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KXG8AZNV1T02 LA KIOXIA:;
1:1049kB:630MB:629MB:fat32:EFI:boot, esp;
2:630MB:6858MB:6228MB:fat32::boot, esp;
3:6859MB:1024GB:1017GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     57F2-06B2                            9f5c7faa-0dc3-4343-aab6-2733fc0164ef 'EFI System EFI
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat     5803-2CD6                            99c1d0bf-a399-475e-bfd3-fd3d740c9e4a PQSERVICE   
└─nvme0n1p3 ext4     ffcf5bd1-a3c8-4f47-b1bc-4e7b29804d23 07641175-8179-4ea2-af91-271f63169746 Ubuntu      

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2                        1.6G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3                      582.3G  32% /
efivarfs                            159.3K  34% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p2                      vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3                      ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

==================== nvme0n1p1/efi/BOOT/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

search.fs_uuid 8D58-976A root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid ffcf5bd1-a3c8-4f47-b1bc-4e7b29804d23 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

If you are seeing this menu, your installation has failed.
Choose from the following options for debugging purposes:

Single User Mode
${title}

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

=================== nvme0n1p3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   ffcf5bd1-a3c8-4f47-b1bc-4e7b29804d23
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
Restore Ubuntu 22.04 to factory state

======================== nvme0n1p3/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=ffcf5bd1-a3c8-4f47-b1bc-4e7b29804d23 /        ext4     errors=remount-ro        0        0
UUID=57F2-06B2   /boot/efi vfat     umask=0077        0        1
/swapfile        none     swap     sw              0        0

==================== nvme0n1p3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p3: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 106.899646759 = 114.782621696  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 622.292663574 = 668.181659648  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  28.656929016 = 30.770143232   boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-1020-oem                    1
 622.292663574 = 668.181659648  boot/vmlinuz-6.11.0-9-generic                  2
 182.050052643 = 195.474755584  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                  2
 182.050052643 = 195.474755584  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 952.436973572 = 1022.671413248 boot/initrd.img                                3
 934.356441498 = 1003.257589760 boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-1020-oem                 8
 952.436973572 = 1022.671413248 boot/initrd.img-6.11.0-9-generic               3
 518.356227875 = 556.580761600  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic               3
 518.356227875 = 556.580761600  boot/initrd.img.old                            3

=================== nvme0n1p3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 18133 Apr   4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 43202 Apr   4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 14513 Apr   4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   786 Apr   4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 13120 Apr   4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1174 Apr   4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   722 Aug  21 20:39 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   214 Dez  18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   215 Dez  18  2022 41_custom
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1439 Sep  25 20:43 99_ubuntu_recovery

============== nvme0n1p3/etc/grub.d/99_ubuntu_recovery (filtered) ==============

#!/bin/bash -e
source /usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
HOOKS=/usr/share/ubuntu/hooks/ubuntu-recovery/grub
[ -d "$HOOKS" ] && \
for i in `ls $HOOKS 2>/dev/null || true`; do
    source "$HOOKS/$i"
echo "Generating 'Restore Ubuntu 22.04 to factory state' entry ..." >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry "Restore Ubuntu 22.04 to factory state"${OPTS} {
        search --no-floppy --hint '(hd0,gpt2)' --set --fs-uuid 5803-2CD6
        if [ -s /boot/grub/common.cfg ]; then
            source /boot/grub/common.cfg
        else
            set options="boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt quiet splash"
        fi
        
        if [ "\${grub_platform}" != "efi" ]; then
            if [ -f \${prefix}/nomodesetlist.txt ]; then
                if hwmatch \${prefix}/nomodesetlist.txt 3; then
                    if [ \${match} != 0 ]; then
                        set options="nomodeset \$options"
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        fi
        #Support starting from a loopback mount (Only support ubuntu.iso for filename)
        if [ -f /ubuntu.iso ]; then
            loopback loop /ubuntu.iso
            set root=(loop)
            set options="\$options iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso"
        fi
        if [ -n "\${lang}" ]; then
            set options="\$options locale=\$lang"
        fi
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz ubuntu-recovery/recovery_type=hdd \$options 
        initrd  /casper/initrd
}
EOF

If I edit the grub entry, and change the root dir from UUID=... to /dev/nvme0n1p3 and then press F10 or Ctrl+X to accept, the system boots. I also tried to set GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true, and it still fails when I directly select the entry, but when I press "e" for edit in the menu and then F10 or Ctrl+X for accepting the changes without changing anything, the system boots successfully.

When I updated my kernel to 6.12 on Ubuntu 24.10, I saw
You need to load the kernel first

Then I disabled secure boot in BIOS, and the kernel loaded successfully.
After the first successful load, I turned secure boot on again
